# Using Loop in SQL Query

Tags: php, sql, database, loops, while-loop

I want to add loop to my sql query so that all the data from the table gets updated at one click. Right now only the last row is getting updated.

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{
$PersonID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['PersonID']);
$FirstName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FirstName']);
$Status = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Status']);
$Date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Date']);




$uname = trim($uname);
$email = trim($email);
$upass = trim($upass);

// email exist or not
$query = "SELECT Date FROM status WHERE Date='$Date'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$count = mysql_num_rows($result); // if email not found then register

if($count == 0){

    if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO status(PersonID,FirstName,Status, Date) VALUES('$PersonID','$FirstName','$Status','$Date')"))
    {
        ?>
        <script>alert('successfully Added ');</script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script>alert('error while registering you...');</script>
        <?php
    }       
}
else{
        ?>
        <script>alert('Sorry Attendence already taken ...');</script>
        <?php
}

}

    echo "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"; 
echo "<html>\n"; 
echo "<head>\n"; 
echo "  <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n"; 
echo "  <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\">\n"; 
echo "  <title>Attendance</title>\n";
echo "</head>\n";
echo "<body>\n";


echo "          \n"; 
echo "\n";
echo "\n";
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$query  = "SELECT * FROM attandance ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<h2>Mark Attendance</h2>\n";
echo "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"\">\n";
echo "<table border=\"2\">\n"; 
echo "   <tr>\n"; 
echo "      <th>PersonId</th>\n"; 
echo "      <th>First Name</th>\n";
echo "      <th>Status</th>\n"; 
echo "      <th>Date</th>\n"; 


echo "    </tr>\n";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{   
    $PersonID=$row['PersonID'];
    $FirstName=$row['FirstName'];
    echo "<td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"PersonID\" value=\" $PersonID\"></td>\n"; 

echo "<td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"FirstName\" value=\" $FirstName\"></td>\n"; 
echo "<td><select name=\"Status\">\n"; 

echo "    <option value=\"Present\">Present</option>\n"; 
echo "    <option value=\"Absent\">Absent</option>\n"; 
echo "  </select></td>\n"; 
echo "<td> <input type=\"date\" name=\"Date\" value=\" $Date\"></td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";



    }




echo " </table>\n";
echo "<input id=\"button\" type=\"submit\" name=\"btn-signup\" value=\"Mark\">\n";
echo "</form>\n";
echo "\n";
echo "\n";
echo "<a href='sheet.php'>Attendence Sheet</a>\n";
echo "</body>\n";
echo "</html>\n";
echo "\n";
?>
```

I am confused as i have used loop in the 2nd part to get value from the database and now i want to use loop to add those value in the database table. How can i add the code to the Insert SQL query in the first part of my code.

Comment: if I see it correctly, you are not updating any records, but inserting a new one. If you want to update (specific) records, you should use `UPDATE` in combination with a fitting `WHERE` clause. But, in your scenario for registering a new user, you are most likely doing the right thing anyway

Comment: I am adding the value of old table to a new table with some new fields. But in my case only the last row is only getting inserted. Not all the rows that i am submitting

Comment: So only the last row is getting added, but you're seeing the "successfully added" alert for all rows?

Comment: i think the last value in the $PersonID, $FirstName, $Date, $Status is inserted thats why only the last row get inserted i want to insert all the value using loop